# Большая нагрузка при вычислении статистики онлайн пользователей

Tags: статистика, php

Есть программа, которая хорошо работает на Denwer, но на самом же сайте он выдаёт 2000% нагрузки. Как снизить такую большую нагрузку на сервер?

```
<?php
// определение ip и времени
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // ip пользователя
$time=time(); // время

// ищем в файле ip подключившегося
$lines = file('online.txt');
foreach($lines as $num_line => $line_value)
{
    if(strpos($line_value, $ip) !== FALSE) {
        // если нашли удаляем
        $file = file("online.txt"); // Считываем весь файл в массив
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($file); $i++)
            if($i == $num_line) unset($file[$i]);
        $fp1 = fopen("online.txt", "w");
        fputs($fp1, implode("", $file));
        fclose($fp1);
    }
}

// разделяем ip-время и оставляем только время, если время больше 90 то удаляем строчку, и так проверяем каждую строчку
// разделение
$fl=fopen("online.txt","r+");
while (!feof($fl)) {
    $a=fgets($fl,4096); // или другая длина, может там предполагается меньше символов в строке
    $ip1=explode("-", $a);
    // определяем сколько времени прошло
    $c=$time-$ip1[1];
    // если больше 90 сек то
    if($c>90) {
        // ищем строчку в которой указано это время
        $lines = file('online.txt');
        foreach($lines as $num_line => $line_value)
        {
            if(strpos($line_value, $ip1[1]) !== FALSE) {
                // и удаляем
                $file1 = file("online.txt"); // Считываем весь файл в массив
                for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($file1); $i++) {
                    if($i == $num_line) unset($file1[$i]);
                }

                $fp2 = fopen("online.txt", "w");
                @fputs($fp2, implode("", $file1));
                fclose($fp2);
            }          
        }
    }
}
fclose($fl);
// запись ip и времени в файл
$fp=fopen('online.txt', 'a+');
$online=$ip."-".$time."\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $online);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Советую бросить эти извращения с текстовыми файлами и юзать БД.
http://toster.ru/q/823